# Shift between OpenLayers and vector layer QGIS 2.20

Tags: qgis, openlayers, vector

Can you please help me solve this issue with OpenLayers Plugin. I see some shift with a vector layer of Laos water boundaries when the background is Google Physical Layer.  I am using CRS EPSG:32647 (UTM 47N). QGIS version is 2.2.0.

Please see the picture attached.

[image]

Comment: You have to keep the spatial reference as EPSG:3857, because Google's Tiles are in that projection. You cannot use any other projection.